# Did I just watch my NVMe drive fail? Or possibly my motherboard?

Tags: ubuntu, hardware, drive-failure

**Update: SOLVED**

*Seems that the drive was in fact the issue. By keeping it **very** cool and moving very slowly and taking breaks, I was able to recover all of its data one file at a time. Thanks all for the help!*

---

My system contains a single Mushkin MKNSSDPE2TB-D8 system drive (a 2TB NVMe SSD) and two SATA drives in a mirrored RAID array. Ubuntu Server 22.04 was installed 4 weeks ago, Oct 7 (+/- a few days) without issue.

I recently began writing files to the system drive, with about 200GB written in the last 48 hours. Multiple system crashes were noted, with the system becoming unresponsive and requiring a hard reboot each time. To diagnose, I began monitoring the kernel message buffer (`sudo dmesg -wH`).

I then wrote a small (339 KB) file to the system drive at Nov 7 18:11 (for reference later).

At this point, the system became unresponsive. Multiple errors accumulated in the kernel message buffer suggesting an issue with the nvme system drive (or possibly the controller?):

```
[ +0.000027] nvme nvme0: I/O 257 QID 5 timeout, aborting
[ +0.000006] nvme nvme0: I/O 258 QID 5 timeout, aborting
[ +0.000005] nvme nvme0: I/O 259 QID 5 timeout, aborting
[ +0.000004] nvme nvme0: I/O 260 QID 5 timeout, aborting
[ +30.719233] nvme nvme0: I/O 256 QID 5 timeout, reset controller
[Nov 7 18:12] nvme nvme0: I/O 2 QID 0 timeout, reset controller
```

Multiple service then began to fail. Finally, I saw the following:

```
[ +0.032544] systemd[1]: Unmounting /boot/efi...
[ +0.000100] systemd[1]: Stopped Journal Service.
[ +0.001581] systemd[1]: Starting Journal Service...
[ +0.005176] systemd[1]: Stopping LVM event activation on device 259:3...
[ +0.000097] systemd[1]: Stopping Unattended Upgrades Shutdown...
[ +0.004093] systemd[1]: lvm2-pvscan@259:3.service: Deactivated successfully.
[ +0.000122] systemd[1]: Stopped LVM event activation on device 259:3.
[ +0.000869] systemd[1]: Started Journal Service.
[ +0.031798] FAT-fs (nvme0n1p1): unable to read boot sector to mark fs as dirty
[Nov 7 18:21] Core dump to |/usr/share/apport/apport pipe failed
[Nov 7 18:22] EXT4-fs warning: 126 callbacks suppressed
[ +0.000001] EXT4-fs warning (device dm-0): ext4_dx_find_entry:1791: inode #5375122: lblock 2: comm PMS ReqHandler: error -5 reading directory block
[ +0.001141] EXT4-fs warning (device dm-0): ext4_dx_find_entry:1791: inode #5375072: lblock 3: comm PMS ReqHandler: error -5 reading directory block
[ +0.000044] EXT4-fs warning (device dm-0): dx_probe:820: inode #5374089: lblock 0: comm PMS ReqHandler: error -5 reading directory block
[ +0.001368] EXT4-fs warning (device dm-0): ext4_dx_find_entry:1791: inode #5375122: lblock 6: comm PMS ReqHandler: error -5 reading directory block
[ +0.000895] EXT4-fs warning (device dm-0): dx_probe:820: inode #5374089: lblock 0: comm PMS ReqHandler: error -5 reading directory block
[ +0.012023] EXT4-fs warning (device dm-0): ext4_dx_find_entry:1791: inode #5375072: lblock 1: comm PMS ReqHandler: error -5 reading directory block
[Nov 7 18:26] Core dump to |/usr/share/apport/apport pipe failed
```

At this point, the system fully failed and was not responsive. A hard reboot was required to get the system back up and running.

The full logs are visible in [this Pastebin document](https://pastebin.com/a73Bi0RF).

Am I watching my NVMe fail? Or could this be a motherboard/controller issue? Any thoughts on how to proceed? I do not have another system that I could use to test the NVMe drive, nor do I have another NVMe drive to test the system. :/

Thank you!!!!! :D

Comment: If you can avoid accidentally issuing destructive commands, I would recommend you *ask the drive* about its status, using the `smartctl` and/or `nvme` utility. Nowadays they know a bit more about their internal checks than the kernel (unsuccessfully) reading and writing blocks will tell you.

Comment: Your kernel says it loaded new processor microcode. That should only happen if your firmware did not deal with that. Now that is probably not helpful *now*.. but next time you install a new system you probably want to start with the mainboard vendors current firmware, clearing your diagnostic attempts from unrelated stability issues that are already resolved for anyone else using that chipset/cpu combo.

Comment: Its probably worth taking out every RAM and NVMe drive and reinserting into a different slots. If you do not have enough unused slots so that would result in a supported configuration, merely swapping slots is also fairly reliable in resolving (or making more obvious) electrical contact issues.

Comment: `That should only happen if your firmware did not deal with that.` I think you can't hardly find a  (consumer-grade) vendor that would actually release firmware updates for microcode updates. You are lucky if the vendor even did it once within the lifetime of the mainboard (probably it's a by-the-way inclusion). It sort of makes sense as well because firmware update is by nature more or less risky. When there's a way the OS (in the broad sense) can deal with it, there's indeed not a strong reason for the vendor to take care of it. (It's not like CPU vulnerability is rare anymore these days...)

Comment: Thanks anx and Tom for the thoughts. This is a good thing to keep in mind for future builds!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had a look at your pastebin and that doesn't look good :(

I'm going to throw ideas your way anyway:

1. NVME tend to run hot when heavily used. If it's overheating, it could cause premature wear and odd behavior. Adding a heatsink (with thermal pads) might help.
2. See if the drive is properly seated. You might also want to remove the drive and check with a flashlight to see if the slot is clean and all the wires (connections) are fine. You could try and spray compressed air in there for good measure.
3. If possible, as a last resort, try to install the drive in a different motherboard or an external enclosure if you have one and see what happens.

If the data on the drive is important / not backed-up, I would remove the drive from the motherboard and try to put it in an external enclosure first. NVME USB enclosures can be had for around 20$ and you would probably have the best chance of retrieving your data this way.

EDIT: You mention not having access to another system so you can always boot your system with a USB stick (live distribution). This will allow you to go to a console, mount your drive (either straight from your motherboard OR, preferably IMO, from a USB-NVME enclosure) and see if your files are there. Once your data is backed-up, you can test your drive and pinpoint what the problem is. I'd begin with smartctl (smartmontools).

Comment: Thanks very much for taking time to review the lengthy logging in Pastebin, and for your thoughts and advice! I've ordered another NVME system drive (I'll need it anyhow) and will take your advice to try booting from a live USB and backup to the new drive to the extent possible.

Fortunately, there was little important data on this drive as it was mostly just running the OS and Docker, with nearly all of the data on the mirrored RAID array. The biggest loss is the set of helper scripts I wrote to remember how to do tedious/obscure tasks. :D

Comment: Damn. I hope you can salvage those scripts! Hopefully your drive is fine too but unless something changed on your system prior the issue happening, it doesn't look good. Last piece of advice, if you do get your drive to work in a USB enclosure, start by copying manually your scripts files. That shouldn't be enough to heat up the drive. If it fails at some point, a USB enclosure could allow quick disconnect/reconnect to try and get a few more bits out of there.

Comment: A happy update! For now, it seems that it was in fact the NVMe drive. I purchased a new drive, booted from a Live USB, and tried copying files over. The original drive would become unavailable at random points and the system would fall over. I setup a few fans pointing at it to keep it cool (in addition to its heatsink), and then wrote a script to copy a few GB at a time before pausing for 30 seconds. Then I ran it and was able to recover all of my data! And because I was within 30 days, I'm able to return my drive for a refund (thanks Amazon : ). Thanks again for your tips.

Comment: Wow! That's about as good as it could turn out! Glad you could recover your scripts! Cheers!